# Reset ReplaySubject value

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs, rxjs-pipeable-operators

I have such file structure:

- facade.ts
- state.ts
- component.ts

In `facade` I have:

```
...
getArticles(): Observable<Article> {
  return this.articleService.fetchAll();
}
...
```

In `state` I have:

```
...
triggerArticlesFetch$ = new ReplaySubject<void>(1);

articles$ = this.triggerArticlesFetch$.pipe(
  switchMap(() => this.fc.getArticles()),
  shareReplay(1)
);

loadArticles(): void {
  this.triggerArticlesFetch$.next();
}

getArticles(): Observable<ArticleShare[]> {
  return this.articles$;
}
...
```

and finally in `component` I have:

```
...
`
  <span> {{ articles$ | async | json }} </span>
`
...
...
articles$: Observable<Article> = this.st.getArticles();

ngOnInit() {
  this.st.loadArticles();
}
...
```

But I have some issues with 'invalidating' this data (component is reusable - and state contains previous data).

What is the best way to clear/reset to `[]/null`  `articles$` (probably in state file) everytime I call `loadArticles()` ?

Comment: "_everytime I call `loadArticles()`_" - by this do you mean every time a new component is initialized?

Comment: @MichaelD some kind of yes... also thought about some magic inside  `ngOnDestroy` - but imo it's a dirty hack.

Comment: I've posted an answer with `startWith` operator. Please see if it works.

Comment: sorry, deleted accidentally the question :)) kind of yes... but it won't work if I update my code to look so (so, actually added one more ReplaySubj to add isFetching state): loadArticles(): void {   this.isArticlesFetching$.next(true);   this.triggerArticlesFetch$.next(); }  articles$ = this.triggerArticlesFetch$.pipe(   switchMap(() => this.fc.getArticles().pipe(switchMap(null))),   tap(() => this.isArticlesFetching$.next(false)),   shareReplay(1) ); in case from my original question -> it works. thx  @MichaelD

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Expanding from my comment (and as I understand) the observable should start with `[]` (or `null`) each time a component is initialized. The quickest fix I could think of is to pipe in a `startWith` to the source.

Try the following

**state**

```js
...
triggerArticlesFetch$ = new ReplaySubject<void>(1);

articles$ = this.triggerArticlesFetch$.pipe(
  switchMap(() => 
    this.fc.getArticles().pipe(
      startWith([]) // or `null` as per requirement
    )
  ),
  shareReplay(1)
);
```

Comment: can you check my comment please?